# How to parse SoapPrimitive String response into intger

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I want to Parse String response into integer but its give zero value.the response is "-1"
Plz Help.

```
       // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
           String value = response.toString();

            loginStatus = Integer.getInteger(value);
```

Comment: Yar koi to answer dedo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer.getInteger(prop_name) returns value of system property of name 'prop_name'.
correct parsing will be:
loginStatus = Integer.parseInt(value);